# How to get a file from WEB-INF from a static method in the test directory on a appengine-app

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to read from the web-inf directory on a static method on a test

```
public static void getSource(){
    File file = Paths.get("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/schemas/tmp.json").toFile();
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.nio.file.Paths is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment
```

classes which are not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment could not be used also for tests?

if so how can I read from the WEB-INF directry on a test from a static method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add on the `pom` file:

```
   <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.6</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

and then use this:

```
 InputStream inputStream = new FileSystemResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/schemas/tmp.json").getInputStream();
```